# React installation fails while trying to execute?

Tags: reactjs

I can't install react.it is showing as follows and no progress afterthat...

```
  "Installing packages.This might take a couple of minutes.
   Installing react,react- and react-scripts with cra-template..."
```

I thought it 'll be because of network issues so kept as it is for more than 3 hrs...but no progress at all.I don't know why it is not going further...

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall, if it exists:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

Install using npx (https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html):

```
npx create-react-app {directory name}
```